# root directory is displayed twice in URL on load and reload

Tags: laravel, url, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I am trying to build an app using Laravel with Jetstream and Inertia + Vue.js.

URL looks like this : https://website/app/route

When I first visit the page, it loads and the URL changes to this : https://website/app/app/route. The page displays its content correctly.

If I reload, I have a 404 message. I have to remove one "/app" to display the content the right way again.

If I don't reload, I can navigate on the page whithout any problem.

Anyone has an idea ?

[image]

[image]

.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried removing /app from APP_URL and ASSET_URL but no change occurs

```
APP_URL=https://website/app
ASSET_URL=https://website/app
```

Comment: looks like you are adding some form of redirect without checking if the URL already contains that redirect?  Something you have done in htaccess ?

Comment: may you need to set APP_URL properly and then "php artisan optimize"

Comment: sorry for the just random words, just for test: lunettes, peugeot, ninjutsu, quinoa, fromage

Comment: I added more details @Snapey

Comment: I dont get it lol @boolfalse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer is what follows :

in vendor/inertiajs/src/Response.php in toResponse() method the URL is built this way:

```
$page = [
            'component' => $this->component,
            'props' => $props,
            'url' => $request->getBaseUrl().$request->getRequestUri(),
            'version' => $this->version,
        ];
```

I overrided this file and changed it to :

```
$page = [
            'component' => $this->component,
            'props' => $props,
            'url' => $request->getRequestUri(),
            'version' => $this->version,
        ];
```